# No git commands (status, show origin) not working, OS X Lion

Tags: macos, git

I was working on a git repo, and because it seemed like my machine was slowing down (and had about 15 days of uptime), I decided to restart. I immediately opened iTerm2, and went back to work, but git is not responding to any commands. I'll paste the output of my console, so you can see me trying things, giving up after 2 minutes of getting no response, checking the path to git to make sure it's installed, etc.

```
Nick-Coxs-Macbook-Pro:codealong macbookpro$ git status
^C
Nick-Coxs-Macbook-Pro:codealong macbookpro$ git gc
^C
Nick-Coxs-Macbook-Pro:codealong macbookpro$ git stash
^C
Nick-Coxs-Macbook-Pro:codealong macbookpro$ git reset --hard HEAD^
^C
Nick-Coxs-Macbook-Pro:codealong macbookpro$ which git
/usr/bin/git
Nick-Coxs-Macbook-Pro:codealong macbookpro$ git status
```

You can see with the `^C` that I've just pressed ctrl + C to get out of it.

A few things I'm sure of:

1. I'm definitely connected to the internet. (Proof: I posted this question.) Even if I weren't, git should still work locally.
2. This is definitely a git repo. Even if it weren't, git would say it wasn't. It wouldn't just hang.
3. I've also tried this in plain Terminal (as opposed to iTerm2). No difference.
4. I'm on OS X Lion 10.7.4.

UPDATE: I've repaired permissions on my machine with Disk Utility, and this is still happening on ALL git repos on my machine.

UPDATE2: Here is the output of my console while git is doing nothing.

```
10/20/12 7:23:48.364 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.Eltima.SyncMateServer[543]) posix_spawn("/Library/Application Support/EltimaSyncMate/SyncMateServer.app/Contents/MacOS/SyncMateServer", ...): No such file or directory
10/20/12 7:23:48.365 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.Eltima.SyncMateServer[543]) Exited with code: 1
10/20/12 7:23:48.365 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.Eltima.SyncMateServer) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

That doesn't mean anything to me. Anyone?

UPDATE3: I don't know why I didn't check this earlier, but I am able to use GitX as a GUI for git, so it's not that git doesn't work per se, but CLI doesn't work.

UPDATE 4: I restarted in Safe Mode, but terminal still treats git the same way.

Comment: It's not normal for a system to get slow from running that long. You might want to troubleshoot that as well.

Comment: Check if the remote server is up and running. Try git remote -v to see if you get any response from git. If you recently upgraded OS X (and haven't run git since then) you might want to reinstall it.

Comment: Your repository isn't gigantic, by any chance, is it?  `du -s -h .git` will show you...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! My repo isn't gigantic at all. I created a new rails app and added a single model. Also, `git remote -v` had the same issue, and I haven't upgraded OS X in a really long time.

Comment: Also, this happens on all git repos on my machine.

Comment: You might consider doing a repair cycle with Disk Utility.

Comment: @Burbas: A problem with the remote server wouldn't affect most of those commands. @nick: Do non-git commands work on the same files and directories? For example, try `find . -type f | xargs sha1sum | wc`; the output isn't particularly meaningful except that it will confirm the ability to read the contents of all file files in the directory tree. If it fails, you have a problem that isn't directly related to git.

Comment: Open your Console app. Do you get any errors when running git?

Comment: @KeithThompson, your find function at least returned something, so it seems that it does have to do with git?

Comment: These console errors don't look like anything related to git. Probably you didn't uninstall SyncMate app properly. Try rebooting your mac in safe mode (few drivers and other things won't run) and check if git works.

Comment: @JuanSosa, see my latest update. Starting in safe mode makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure why this was happening, but I was able to fix it. I uninstalled git with a simple `rm /usr/local/bin/git` (which would, of course, change based on the location of the installation), then I reinstalled it with [this installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/detail?name=git-1.8.0-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg) (note that it worked for 10.7 Lion, even though it is ostensibly the Snow Leopard binary) because I found out that `git` was just recently updated to 1.8.